# Prolog Second Minimum value on a list

Tags: prolog, logic

I am new to prolog and Im looking for some advice. I am working in building a code that defines a predicate secondMin/2 with the signature secondMin(list, Min2) where Min2 is the second lowest value element in some list of numbers. If the list has fewer than two elements, then your predicate should display the following, "Error: list has fewer than two elements." If one more elemenets of list is not a number, then your predicate should display the following "ERROR "element is not a number". 
Examples:

```
secondMin([17,29,11,62], Min2).
Min2 = 17

secondMin([512], Min2).
Error: List has fewer than two elements.

secondmin([12,2,b,7], Min).
Error: "b" is not a number.
```

I implemented a code that finds the smallest value on the list I just need help on how to implement the second smallets value and how to check for errors.

```
x = integer.
    l = integer*.

    minlist(l,x).
    min(x,x,x).

    min(X,Y,Min) :-
        X < Y,!,
        Min = X.

    min(X,Y,Min) :-
        Min = Y.

    minlist([],0).
    minlist([X],X).
    minlist([X,Y|List],Min) :-
        min(X,Y,Min1),
        minlist([Min1|List],Min).
```

Comment: You have a tag `swi-prolog` but the syntax you are showing looks like Turbo, Visual, or PDC Prolog. Which is it really? It makes a difference in this case since Turbo/Visual/PDC deviate significantly from the ISO standard and don't have the same pre-defined predicates.

Comment: The minimum of an empty list is not zero... It doesn't exist.